# Programmatically saving data in a field under user account

Tags: 8, users

QR codes have been printed out for a bunch of students in a university.
When they visit the site via those QR codes, and they are logged-in, the *refcode* query parameter used in the link needs to be saved for their account in a *field_usr_ref_code* field (a *Text (plain)* field).

In a .module file I am using the following code.

```php
use Drupal\user\Entity\User;

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_load().
 */
function my_custom_module_entity_load() {
  $refcode = \Drupal::request()->query->get('refcode');
  $user_id = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();
  if ($user_id > '0' && isset($refcode)) {
    $account = User::load($user_id);    
    $account->set('field_usr_ref_code', $refcode);
    $account->save();
  }
}
```

However, for some reason no data is being saved, without any logged error.

What is wrong with the code I am using?

Comment: Quotes are for strings,  not for numbers/integers. `$currentuserid > '0'` is best to have as `$currentuserid > 0`. In addition, `else { // Do nothing }` if you are  really doing nothing, then delete the else code, as having an else is not mandatory for if statements.

Comment: However, despite having those 2 blemishes that I pointed out in my previous comment, your code should've worked. So your issue is else where. In the hook function name, did you rename the `my_custom_module` part to your actual custom module's name? Did you make sure your module is indeed enabled? You could also add `\Drupal::logger('my_custom_module')->notice('My HOOK works!');` in your hook code to check that your hook is needed being executed. Then go to `/admin/reports/dblog` and check if it got logged.

Comment: Drupal 8 is end of life. Each day the risk increases that the site will be hacked.

Comment: @NoSssweat I have updated my code based on your input; And yes the module is enabled, all caches are cleared and the module is renamed as it should be... Still not working

Comment: Is the module’s meta file named my_custom_module.info.yml?

Comment: Yes, the module is already working and contains another function which is: `function my_custom_module_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {}`

Comment: `hook_entity_load()` is the wrong hook to use for code that should be executed when a page is visited.

Comment: Truly, and it has the wrong signature.

Comment: @apaderno can you suggest what function should be use instead ?

Answer (score 1):

Use a request event subscriber with a priority of 299:

*/src/EventSubscriber/MymoduleSubscriber.php*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;

/**
 * Mymodule event subscriber.
 */
class MymoduleSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  /**
   * Kernel request event handler.
   *
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent $event
   *   The request event.
   */
  public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event) {
    if (!$event->isMainRequest()) {
      return;
    }
    // put here your code
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return [
      KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onKernelRequest', 299],
    ];
  }
}
```

*mymodule.services.yml*

```
services:
  mymodule.event_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\MymoduleSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```

Drupal runs authentication with priority 300.

This code is for Drupal 9/10.

For Drupal 8 you need to use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent and $event->isMasterRequest().

Comment: For Drupal 8 you need to use Drupal 9 